# C# - window form application - Close the application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want a help. I have a window form application. Whenever I click on the "close" of the form, the application should itself close.

Can anyone help me.

Regards,
Justin Samuel.

Comment: What is happening when you click close? When you say close do you mean the Cross at the top right or is this a command button close?

Comment: Yes, I mean the cross at the top of the window.

Comment: I am referring to the cross at the top of the window.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add anything, so I suspect something is intercepting your event - unless you've removed some auto code.

Can you step through the put a breakpoint after the form load, start to step through so that the form is displayed. Then click the close button. Step through and see where the code goes.

Also, try addign a new form and closing that - does it work?

Comment: You will have to tell us more details. As the answers show, the App normally closes when the Main Window coses.

Comment: Sorry.... But actually I have a small form on whose button click a new form pops up. Now I am expecting to close the application as the user closes this second window(ie cross on top right is pressed).
Note: The first form is hiding on opening the second form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After your explanation:

In Form1, do something like:

```
  Form2 f2 = new Form2();
  f2.ShowDialog();
  this.Close();
  Application.Exit();
```

This is assuming Form2 can be shown Modal (Dialog), which I think is correct

Comment: I have tried your solution but it is not working. I missed one point. In the second form I am starting a thread. Could this be any interfering point?

Comment: Justin, Yes, if the thread is __not__ a background thread it will keep your process running.

Comment: Yes my thread had an open TcpClient object. All I needed was to close this object and it worked very fine!! 
Thanks Henk for the guidance!

Answer (score 2):

A Winforms application will exit automatically when the main form is closed. The main form is the form that is instantiated and passed to Application.Run method in the Main method of the application.

If the application process does not exit when this form is closed, something is preventing it from closing, such as a thread (that is not a background thread) that is performing some work.

Answer (score 2):

By your description, it sounds like you may have multiple forms in your application and one form is still running even if its's not visible. In this case, the close button, would close the form, but not exit the application.

You need to add an event handler for the [Form_FormClosed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx) event and then call [Application.Exit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exit.aspx) - Ideally, you could also handle the [Form_FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) event if you want to give the user a dialog to ask if they really meant to close.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the [`Application.Exit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894%28VS.80%29.aspx) method.